# Error when running BlockManager in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm running a pyspark script locally that takes two files are compares data from both. Once the data is compared, a new file is saved to my machine.

Halfway through the code I get the following error:

```
ERROR RetryingBlockTransferor: Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks 
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.105:58072
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:288)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:218)
        at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$2.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockTransferor.transferAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockTransferor.java:154)
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockTransferor.start(RetryingBlockTransferor.java:133)
        at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.fetchBlocks(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.fetchRemoteManagedBuffer(BlockManager.scala:1119)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$getRemoteBlock$8(BlockManager.scala:1063)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBlock(BlockManager.scala:1063)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:1201)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3.$anonfun$run$1(TaskResultGetter.scala:88)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.1.105:58072
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm running the following `spark-submit` command

```
spark-submit --master local --driver-memory 5g --conf spark.sql.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead=CORRECTED --conf spark.sql.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite=CORRECTED --conf spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead=CORRECTED
```

I've researched a few errors like this but the answers didn't resolve mine. I think it's configuration, just not sure what configurations need to be changed.

Comment: Are you running on windows or linux based machine? Possibly issue in resolving hostname.